# Azure Application Insights - Setting up the user name in the request?

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

If I make a request to an api that has the application insights SDK installed and inform a valid `traceparent` header, the SDK will populate the `operation_id` field accordantly.

Is there a way to make the SDK do the same for the `user_id` or `user_authenticatedid` or other fields? or do I have to fill them myself?

Comment: take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979452/filling-user-id-field-in-application-insights-from-asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do it "manually", my question is wether there's a OOB way to do it... like, "just have the client put a header named X-User-Id and you're good to go"

Answer (score 0):

You can add users id to the telemetries if this solves your problem.

[image]

The last 5 attributes were added by our logging middleware. If this is what you looking for you can use a similar approach.